# Balls and Bins - high probability bounds on the sum of squared loads

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables, balls-in-bins

Consider throwing $m$ balls into $n$ bins uniformly at random, and let $X_i$ denote the number of balls that fall in bin $i$.

Denote by $S=\sum_{i=1}^n X_i^2$ the sum of square loads on the bins.

I am looking for a high-probability upper bound on $S$, i.e., a quantity $B_{m,n}$ such that 
$$ \Pr\left[S \ge B_{m,n}\right]\le 1/n.$$

This question is motivated by an algorithm that uses fingerprints instead of ids for the balls and wishes to guarantee that with high probability there is no fingerprint collision between balls in the same bin (but there can be across bins). Since the probability of collision in bin $i$ is proportional to $X_i^2$, setting a fingerprint length proportional to $\log S$ will guarantee the correctness with high probability.

> **How can we derive a high probability upper bound for $S$?**

---

One naive approach would be to use known high probability bounds on the maximum load. For example, if $m=n$ we have that the maximum load is bounded by $(2+o(1))\cdot \log n / \log\log n$ with high probability. This implies that we can set $B_{m,n} = (4+o(1))\cdot n\cdot\left(\log n / \log\log n\right)^2$.
However, this seems like a *very* loose bound. How can we improve it (hopefully, for arbitrary $m$)?

Comment: What is high probability?

Comment: @greedoid, $1-1/n$ would be good.

Comment: No, what is the definition of high probability?

Comment: @greedoid - Probability that approaches $1$ when $n\to \infty$, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/With_high_probability.

Comment: @greedoid - thanks for your comments. I edited the post, can you please see if now it is clear? Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure, but are similar tight bounds known for arbitrary order statistics of balls and bins, besides the maximum? If so, you could try bounding the top $f(n)$ terms by the size of the largest bin, and the remaining bins by the size of the $f(n)$-th largest bin for any suitable function of $n$. (Basically you are claiming the bound you gave is not tight because most bins are not so full, but you'll need an asymptotic justification for that.)

Comment: @TMM - exactly, I believe that the right bound should be $O(n)$ (for $m=n$) but am not sure how to prove this. Do you know a simple bound on the size of the $f(n)$'th largest bin? My guess is that it won't bring us all the way down to $O(n)$ but will probably better than paying this $\log^2 n$ factor.